# No Gradle file syntax highlighting in Eclipse Mars.2

Tags: eclipse, gradle, eclipse-plugin

Wondering if anyone else met with the same issue, I open gradle file in Eclipse (Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)), there is no highlights for gradle syntax. I install Gradle plug-in for Eclipse from http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship/downloads.

I tried the same plug-in in Eclipse 4.4.1, but no such issues. Any advice is appreciated.

It seems I have installed a few Gradle plug-in. Post my screen snapshots.

[image]

Post my show view screen snapshots,

[image]

Comment: I also installed the Gradle plug-in v1.0.10 from http://download.eclipse.org/buildship/updates/e45/releases/1.0 (note the e45) in Mars.2 and can confirm that there is **no** syntax highlighting.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann, thanks for the confirmation, if no highlight, the plug-in is totally useless? Does it perform any other tasks related to Gradle besides syntax highlight?

Comment: Not sure, I am as well new to Gradle in Eclipse. Did you look into the _Gradle_ views and launch configurations?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann, do you mean Windows => Show View? I do not find anything related to Gradle there. I am using Eclipse 4.5.2, if you have any advice, it will be highly appreciated. vote up. :)

Comment: <kbd>Alt+Shift+Q Q</kbd> or _Window > Show View > Other_ lists all available views. If you don't find the mentioned views there, then the Gradle plug-in isn't installed (properly). In the About dialog, there should be a Gradle icon. Also make sure to have the minimum required JRE installed.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann, thanks and vote up. Post my show view screen snapshots, which one do you mean?. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tried in Eclipse 4.4.2: No syntax highlighting. Maybe you have the [Gradle IDE Pack by Nodeclipse/Enide](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-ide-pack) installed in your 4.4.1?

Update: So I just saw you have **both** buildship and the Gradle IDE Pack installed. This will install multiple editors for `.gradle` files:

1. "Gradle Build Script Editor" (buildship, on the left)
2. "Minimalist Gradle Editor" (Gradle IDE Pack, on the right)

[image: Editor comparison]

To open a `.gradle` file with another type of editor, right-click the file and select "Open With":
[image: open-with context menu]

---

I advise against using multiple Gradle plugins, as you can get confused by which plugin does what. You should stick with the one that suits you best.

Comment: Hi Alex, which one do you suggest me to use for 4.5.2?

Comment: I personally prefer the buildship plug-in over the Gradle IDE Pack (linked above), because the integration with the Gradle tooling API was better. If you want syntax highlighting, you should give the Gradle IDE Pack a try. I just confirmed it has syntax highlighting. If you want **just** the syntax highlighting, you can use [this plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/minimalist-gradle-editor).

Comment: Thanks Axel, vote up. :)

I tried in Eclipse 4.5.2, using this link, http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/gradle-ide-pack/, but it does not support syntax highlight. If you have any further advice, it will be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: Hi Axel, it seems I already installed the plug-in. Post my screen snapshots in my original post, your advice is appreciated. :)

Comment: Thanks for all the help Axel, mark your reply as answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not implemented in buildship yet. See discussion here 
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-build-script-editor/12079.

Use either the Groovy editor or the Nodeclipse Minimalist editor (http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle/).

Comment: Thanks satolizard, does it mean no Gradle plug-in for Eclipse Mars.2? Just want to confirm my understanding is correct.

Comment: No, there are gradle plugins that work for Mars. Buildship and Spring Tools do (although Spring is phasing out - see [here](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/wiki/Migration-guide-from-STS-Gradle-to-Buildship)). It's just that the syntax highlighting feature is not there. But you can install NodeEclipse minimalist editor along side one of these so you can get both.

Comment: Thanks satolizard, vote up for the reply. I think syntax highlight is all the features? Besides syntax highlight, what are other functions from Gradle we can benefit from the plug-ins? :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to replace IDE pack and minimalist editor with [egradle](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/egradle-editor) editor that features both syntax highlight and can also show something meaningful in the outline view. At the time of writing under Eclipse Oxygen none of the other two mentioned editors are capable of this.

I only Eclipse to edit gradle build files as part of the project. If I need to run them, I use terminal.