# Gradle build file auto-formatting in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, autoformatting

Eclipse Mars.

I've installed the "Minimalist" syntax highlighter editor plugin... as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36069666/no-gradle-file-syntax-highlighting-in-eclipse-mars-2/36070114#36070114), but is there any way currently to get auto-formatting on .gradle files?

It may well be that there's a Groovy auto-formatting editor plugin... but that won't (I presume) do all the syntax highlighting for Gradle.

Comment: I don't know any plugins for that, but there is a in-development text editor which highlights gradle syntax - https://bintray.com/alexiy/maven-repo/jace#read

Comment: Thanks, yes there are one or two options for syntax colouring, etc.  But the beautifying/formatting seems difficult.  Someone said Groovy's semantics make auto-formatting difficult.  Wish they'd gone for Jython instead of Groovy, which at first sight is a sort of half-way house.

Comment: Answered my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48083451/595305

Answer (score 1):

you can use the spotless plugin for gradle to format source files as well as other types of build files including the gradle files.

If you just need something basic, you can format like this:

```
spotless {
    format 'misc' {
       target '*.gradle', '*.md', '.gitignore'

       trimTrailingWhitespace()
       indentWithTabs()
       endWithNewLine()
     }
}
```

This has the benefit of working with any IDE and you can even hook it into the build target to run automatically.

```
afterEvaluate {
    tasks.getByName('spotlessheck').dependsOn('spotlessApply')
}
```

Example with spotless 5.8.2